# unable to find the current configuration of OSSFS/S3FS?

Tags: s3fs, alibaba-cloud

I have connected the Alibaba Cloud OSS bucket using OSSFS. But now I want to change the OSS Bucket to another URL. But I want to check which URL it is configured now?

I have checked the documentation and also the `OSSFS --help` But there is no basic info command available.

Thanks

Comment: What to do you mean by URL? You want to unmount the bucket and then mount it to different path?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure and set the custom domain name to the public endpoint of the bucket.

Refer the following link:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31902.htm